# Swing UI freezes when trying to update from SwingWorker

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I've tried to make a simple Swing example which uses SwingWorker to update the text of a Label. Whenever the SwingWorker finishes and tries to update the text, the UI will freeze. After closing the window it'll show a AWT-EventQueue-0 "Widget is disposed" exception.

I've tried to make sure it's running on the EDT etc, but I think I'm missing something very basic here. Could someone please look at my code and tell me what might be happening?

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

public class MySwingWindow {

    private Label mainText;

    protected Shell shell;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                MySwingWindow window = new MySwingWindow();
                window.open();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();

        try {
            SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
                   @Override
                   protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                     System.out.println("Running " + i);
                    }
                    return true;
                   }

                   @Override
                   protected void done() {
                     mainText.setText("Done");

                   }
                  };

                  worker.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

        mainText = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        mainText.setBounds(78, 84, 55, 15);
        mainText.setText("Working");

    }
}
```

Comment: `I think I'm missing something very basic here.` Why are you mixing SWT and Swing? Those are two different toolkits. Pick one. Your while loop with the "display.sleep()" could be causing the GUI to freeze since you continually sleep. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [Tasks that have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for a working example of using a SwingWorker.

Comment: In fact, your code doesn't show a Swing, but a [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) example. You cannot use _SwingWorker_ in SWT because (in contrast to Swing) SWT has a single UI thread (background jobs are offloaded to other threads, but the UI must be accessed in the UI thread only).

Comment: ... oh god. Thanks guys!